# Convert track data into a bezier curve or a path?

Tags: bezier-curves, motion-capture

I want to do a simple motion trail that has the same path as my track, but different timing. For that I need to **convert the track data into a bezier curve**. Any idea on how to do that? The reconstruct options allows only to make an empty that follows a track, not a path. There is a 3d markers to mesh option but no matter what I do I get *No usable tracks selected Warning*. I could only find very old posts on similar topics but they were talking about f-curves which have unfinished documentation.

I just need a follow path instead of follow track with the same data...

Motion tracking data
[image: Motion tracking data]
Blender documentation on f-curves:
[image: Documentation]

Comment: I'll write this as a comment, since you specified bezier, but I think f-curves should do what you want. There is actually extensive documentation on them in the Graph Editor section: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/introduction.html# including the similarities and differences to beziers.

To convert the track data to an f-curve, reconstruct the track to create an empty, select the empty and you will find "Constraint to F-Curve" in the Follow Track object constraint.